# ggplot: coord_cartesian(clip = "off") and alpha < 1.0 hides geom_lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot, when turning off clipping, lines with alpha < 1.0 are completely ommitted.

Here's an example:

```
## create a dummy data frame:
library(tidyverse)

num_lines <- 10

start_values = runif(num_lines, min = 0, max = 5)
end_values = start_values + runif(num_lines, min = 0, max = 7)

df <- data.frame(from = start_values, to = end_values, 
                 value = runif(num_lines, min = 0, max = 100),
                 name = letters[seq(1, num_lines)])

plot_df <- df %>% gather(milestone, date, -name, - value)

## draw it:
ggplot(plot_df, aes(x = date, y = name)) + 
    geom_line(aes(size = value), color = "grey50", alpha = 0.9) + #### lines are not drawn
    geom_line(linetype = "dashed", alpha = 1.0) +                 #### lines are drawn
    annotate("label", x = num_lines/2, y = num_lines + 1, label = "A label") + #### a label that should not be clipped...
    coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +                                            #### ...therefore: clip = "off"
    ggtitle("Example")
```

When running the code, the first `geom_line` with (...alpha = 0.9) is not drawn while the second one behaves as expected. When removing `coord_cartesian(clip = "off")` both `geom_lines` show up.

Is this a bug in ggplot or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your code works for me (under the dashed lines, I see gray lines of various thickness). I am using ggplot 3.2.0.

Comment: Many thanks - I'm using R 3.6.1 (in the plain R GUI) - then it's maybe some issue with R 3.6.1.

Comment: If you're using the plain R GUI, what graphic device are you drawing the plot onto? Some may not support transparency. I'm using RStudio (free to download), which has an integrated plotting area.

Comment: Good hint - I tried a ```ggsave("test.png", device = "png")``` and the thick lines are shown - so it seems to be an issue with the R GUI graphics device.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is due to the graphic device used to output the plot. Not a code issue.

Comment: You're right - I agree.